# Ways to simplify a neural network in R for interpretation

Tags: r, neural-networks, interpretation

I would like to try to make some sense of a neural network. The neural network has a single hidden layer and is used on 30-40 attributes, which are used to classify the probability that the observation belongs to 1 of 3 different classes. My goal is to the find 5-10 main interactions in order to understand the model better.

To do this I've been recommended by my adviser to look into the 'Optimal Brain Damage'-algorithm (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-90b.pdf), which removes connections between nodes one by one. However, I cannot seem to find any R packages that supports this algorithm.

I would therefore like to know what other algorithms exist to simplify neural networks and make them more easily interpreted. My efforts searching has so far been pretty useless, which is likely due to the fact that I don't have any clue of which key words to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Would regularizing the problem and attempting to enforce sparsity help? The OBD algorithm is not terribly complicated either so implementing it would not be particularly hard.

Comment: Perhaps. Would it be feasible to use forward feature selection with a least squares estimation on the data before using ANN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R package [RSNNS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/index.html) has a plethora of options for training and pruning neural networks, including optimal brain damage and optimal brain surgeon, among others. The software appears to be rather robust. I'm not aware of another package implementing the OBD algorithm in R.

Additionally, the package [NeuralNetTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NeuralNetTools/index.html) provides a few functions that allow one to assess variable importance and how varying levels of feature input influence the output of the network.